# Z3 Java API: FuncDecl and Expr

Tags: z3

I have an existing smt2 file, and used z3 java api parsed this and solved the problem. But I have a question about how to cast a FuncDecl to an Expr because I want to build some simple formula by using z3 java apis.  Since my original formulas is purely written in smt2 text file and everything gets parsed into a single BoolExpr. Now, I successfully extracted the consts, and need to manipulate them with new formula.  How can i do it?  Basically, what I am looking for is how to build an Expr from FuncDecl Or is there a way I can cast it to Expr? Is there any official java api document available? I know there is an example of using z3 java api, but it's pretty painful to look for a specific api description in such a large example.

Answer (score 0):

FuncDecl's are function declarations, they can not be cast directly to expressions, but the function they represent can be applied (to some arguments) to yield an expression. This is what `FuncDecl.apply(...)` does. Constants are of course a special case, where the function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Christoph, thank you for your reply.  The constant has 0 arity, say (declare-const a (Bool)). But now I would like to build a formula from this a, say (and a b).  Since mkXXX (where XXX= and, or, etc.) only works for Expr(BoolExpr). Thus, I cannot use a there directly.  Therefore, how can I build a formula from constant?  Suppose all the function declarations, constants, and other formulas are in an existing smt2 file and have already been successfully parsed and added into Solver.

Comment: Say you have FuncDecl q = ...; Doesn't q.apply() work and produce the right Expr?